# Desactivar inputs de una fila en especifica de una tabla en HTML a traves de un boton

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que necesito es que al darle click al boton "guardar" de una fila en especifico, se desactiven unicamente los inputs de esa fila para que no se puedan editar hasta que se de click en el boton "editar" sin afectar las demas filas , cada fila tiene un boton de "guardar y editar".

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
            <table  class="table table-dark table-bordered table-hover " id="tabla-apuestas">

          <thead >
            <tr>
              <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dia</th>
              <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dinero Metido</th>
              <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dinero Ganado</th>
              <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dinero Perdido</th>
              <th scope="col" colspan="2" class="text-center">¿Terminaste?</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="" class="text-center"><input id="input-1" type="date" ></th>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-2" placeholder="$" type="number"  /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-3" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-4" placeholder="$" type="number"  /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-editar" onclick="activarInputs()" class="bg-warning text-white"> <b>Editar</b> </button></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-guardar" onclick="desactivarInputs()" class="boton bg-success text-white"> <b>Guardar</b> </button></td>
              <label id="respuesta"><label>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th scope="" class="text-center"><input id="input-1" type="date"></th>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-1" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-2" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-3" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-editar" onclick="activarInputs()"  class="bg-warning text-white"> <b>Editar</b> </button></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-guardar" onclick="desactivarInputs()" class="boton bg-success text-white"> <b>Guardar</b> </button></td>
              <label id="respuesta"><label>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th scope="" class="text-center"><input id="input-1" type="date"></th>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-1" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-2" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-3" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-editar" onclick="activarInputs()" class="bg-warning text-white"> <b>Editar</b> </button></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button  id="btn-guardar" onclick="desactivarInputs()" class="boton bg-success text-white"> <b>Guardar</b> </button></td>
              <label id="respuesta"><label>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        
          
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo te propongo la siguiente solución: https://codepen.io/Calamari_love/pen/QWGPqKE

```js
function desactivarInputs(id){
  let parentTr = document.getElementById(id).closest('tr'); 
  let childrenTr = parentTr.children;

  for (c of childrenTr){
    if(c.firstChild.nodeName == 'INPUT'){
      c.firstChild.disabled = true
    }
  }
}

function activarInputs(id){
  let parentTr = document.getElementById(id).closest('tr'); 
  let childrenTr = parentTr.children;

  for (c of childrenTr){
    if(c.firstChild.nodeName == 'INPUT'){
      c.firstChild.disabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 <table  class="table table-dark table-bordered table-hover " id="tabla-apuestas">

          <thead >
            <tr>
              <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dia</th>
              <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dinero Metido</th>
              <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dinero Ganado</th>
              <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dinero Perdido</th>
              <th scope="col" colspan="2" class="text-center">¿Terminaste?</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="" class="text-center"><input id="input-1" type="date" ></th>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-2" placeholder="$" type="number"  /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-3" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-4" placeholder="$" type="number"  /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-editar-1" onclick="activarInputs(this.id)" class="bg-warning text-white"> <b>Editar</b> </button></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-guardar-1" onclick="desactivarInputs(this.id)" class="boton bg-success text-white"> <b>Guardar</b> </button></td>
              <label id="respuesta"><label>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th scope="" class="text-center"><input id="input-1" type="date"></th>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-1" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-2" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-3" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-editar-2" onclick="activarInputs(this.id)"  class="bg-warning text-white"> <b>Editar</b> </button></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-guardar-2" onclick="desactivarInputs(this.id)" class="boton bg-success text-white"> <b>Guardar</b> </button></td>
              <label id="respuesta"><label>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th scope="" class="text-center"><input id="input-1" type="date"></th>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-1" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-2" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><input id="input-3" placeholder="$" type="number" /></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button id="btn-editar-3" onclick="activarInputs(this.id)" class="bg-warning text-white"> <b>Editar</b> </button></td>
              <td class="text-center"><button  id="btn-guardar-3" onclick="desactivarInputs(this.id)" class="boton bg-success text-white"> <b>Guardar</b> </button></td>
              <label id="respuesta"><label>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        
          
        </table>
```

Básicamente, al pulsar sobre uno de los botones de guardar busco el elemento 'tr' más cercano y de ahí ciclo sobre sus elemntos hijos, buscando los que sean inputs y desactivándolos.

Aparte de eso, he tenido que cambiar los IDs de los botones para que sean únicos. Esto creo que es algo que deberías hacer con los demás elementos ya que en HTML no es buena idea repetir los IDs.

Cualquier cosa me comentas!

Edito con el código para la otra consulta:

```
function crearFilas(){
  let parentTr = document.getElementById("tabla-apuestas").children[1];
  let contadorId = 0;
  for (c of parentTr.children){
    contadorId++;
  }
  contadorId = contadorId + 1
  
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu respuesta, me funcionó a la perfección, tomando en cuenta lo de modificar los IDs de los botones, tengo otro boton que es para agregar filas, en este caso como es posible que al agregar una fila me agregue los IDs de los botones siguientes es decir si tengo ya 3 declarados, que al agregar una fila adicional me agregue el id del boton-4 y asi sucesivamente cada que agrego fila.

Comment: Es muy sencillo. Parecido a como lo hemos hecho antes, mediante el ID de la tabla podemos ciclar sobre los hijos, en este caso los 'tr', y con un contador sabremos cuántos 'tr' tiene. Después le sumamos 1 y ya estaría. Edito la respuesta con el código.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, a parte de los errores de HTML que tiene el documento (duplicidad de id, por ejemplo, labels que no son funcionales etc. que estan corregidos) aquí tienes mi resultado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>Pruebas 2</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">

    window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
      getElements();
    })

    function getElements(){
      document.querySelectorAll('.btn-editar').forEach(item=>{
        item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
          activarInputs(e.target.parentNode.parentNode);
        })
      });

    }

    function activarInputs(e){
      var inp = e.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(item=>{
        if(item.getAttribute("disabled")=="true"){
          item.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
        else{
          item.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        }
      });
    }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table  class="table table-dark table-bordered table-hover " id="tabla-apuestas">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dia</th>
        <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dinero Metido</th>
        <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dinero Ganado</th>
        <th scope="col"class="text-center">Dinero Perdido</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2" class="text-center">Terminaste?</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="" class="text-center"><input class="input-1" type="date" ></th>

        <td class="text-center"><input class="input-2" placeholder="$" type="number"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input class="input-3" placeholder="$" type="number"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input class="input-4" placeholder="$" type="number"></td>

        <td class="text-center"><button class="btn-editar bg-warning text-white">Editar</button></td>
        <td class="text-center"><button class="btn-guardar boton bg-success text-white" onclick="desactivarInputs()">Guardar</button></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th scope="" class="text-center"><input class="input-1" type="date" ></th>

        <td class="text-center"><input class="input-2" placeholder="$" type="number"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input class="input-3" placeholder="$" type="number"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input class="input-4" placeholder="$" type="number"></td>

        <td class="text-center"><button class="btn-editar bg-warning text-white">Editar</button></td>
        <td class="text-center"><button class="btn-guardar boton bg-success text-white" onclick="desactivarInputs()">Guardar</button></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th scope="" class="text-center"><input class="input-1" type="date" ></th>

        <td class="text-center"><input class="input-2" placeholder="$" type="number"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input class="input-3" placeholder="$" type="number"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input class="input-4" placeholder="$" type="number"></td>

        <td class="text-center"><button class="btn-editar bg-warning text-white">Editar</button></td>
        <td class="text-center"><button class="btn-guardar boton bg-success text-white" onclick="desactivarInputs()">Guardar</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>          
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Quitando el onclick de los botones, y haciendo una selección pura por JS:

Iniciamos el DOM con un listener, que nos manda a la función getElements.

En dicha función, seleccionamos TODOS los botones con class .btn-editar (primer cambio que hice, de id pasarlo a class, ya que se repetía el id, y generaba errores, es peligroso trabajar con id, ten cuidado), iterar dichos botones ocn el bucle forEach, y añadir a cada item un listener a los clicks, que con cada clic pase el valor e por la función activarInputs.

`e` lo dirigimos al parentNode.parentNode (el padre del padre, y asi será el tr)

Ahí, buscamos todos los input del tr en cuestión, y los deshabilitamos, y si volvemos a pulsar, los habilitamos de nuevo.